# Write multiple hex values in C# (BinaryWriter)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to allow the user to write multiple bytes in a textbox (`textBox1`) to a hexadecimal offset (`toolStripTextBox1`).

The code is:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName)))
{
     bw.Seek(toolStripTextBox1.Text, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     bw.Write((byte)textBox1.Text);
}
```

Unfortunately, it only writer one byte, so let's say I put in `textBox1` `3F468A` and in `toolStripTextBox1` `F00000`, it will write at offset `0xF00000` just the last byte in the 3 bytes I put in `textBox1` (`8A`).

How do I make it write multiple bytes from the `textBox1`, so at `0xF00000`, the `BinaryWriter` will write the hex value `3F468A`, and not just `8A`?

Comment: You are casting the entire Text property to a single byte `(byte)textBox1.Text` so it's truncating.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, neither of your text boxes contain numeric data. You need to convert the **strings** in your text boxes to the correct numeric data type.

Once you've done your conversions correctly, just use the right [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d79ecdwh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload:

```
var seekPos = int.Parse(toolStripTextBox1.Text, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var data = UInt32.Parse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName)))
{
     bw.Seek(seekPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     bw.Write(data); //data is UInt32, correct overload is chosen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

spender,

Thanks for answering, I really appreciate that:

```
 var seekPos = int.Parse(toolStripTextBox1.Text,
 NumberStyles.HexNumber); var data = UInt32.Parse(textBox1.Text,
 NumberStyles.HexNumber); using (BinaryWriter bw = new
 BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName))) {
      bw.Seek(seekPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      bw.Write(data); //data is UInt32, correct overload is chosen }
```

I have tried the code, it works really good, but it writes it in reverse hex (as half word), so if I put in textBox1 424344, it writes in the hex data 44434200.

Also, when I type a single byte, let's say FE, it writes FE000000. If I type FAFBFCFDFE, it gives me an error - "Value was either too large or too small for UInt32".

Do you know why is it doing this?

Thanks